# Bootstrap CSS switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So for the past few weeks I've been developing my portfolio website. My website is mainly based on Bootstrap. 
I've been thinking of doing a multi CSS page so user can change the "theme" by selecting a colour box so once it's clicked the CSS gets reloaded and the page gets new colour.
I've created 2 separate CSS files.

This is what I've got. I couldn't find anything that would work with Bootstrap,
I've tried:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/styleswitch/
and loads of others but I was unable to get it to work with Bootstrap.

Thanks, Pax.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the page color? Do you want to change only backgroud-color of whole page or you want to adjust all other styles in some way?

Comment: I'd like to change the stylesheet completely, not only the background. So lets say I'd like to change navbar colour, background images and fonts. What I mean is the first CSS to be darkgrey colour and second one to be light so complete revamp of the CSS.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with Bootstrap. Why can't you just switch out your CSS with JS/jQuery? Do you make changes to the `bootstrap.css` to create the themes, are you overriding in a separate .css file (ie: theme.css)?

Comment: Well basically what I'm trying to do is to have few style sheets and once user clicks on the image or something page reloads with new colours and new stylesheet that is replaced by the old one. I don't know what it has to do with bootstrap but it doesn't work but it should.

Comment: You can try to do it yourself, without any plugins. If you use HTML5 on your page, google for localStorage (example reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). It's a form of browser-based session that can store variables. You could e.g. set such variable everytime user clicks on stylesheet and use the variable's value to link new styles. Give it a try.

Comment: I've managed to sort it out I had to add some tweaks to jQuery code. Thanks everyone.